# Why doesn't the number times properly?

Tags: python

My code:

```
binary_value = list(input("Input a binary number: "))

def binaryToDecimal(binary_value):
    last_number = (binary_value[-1])
    last_numberi = (last_number * pow(2,0))

    last_number2 = (binary_value[-2])
    last_number2i = (last_number2 * pow(2,1))

    last_number3 = (binary_value[-3])
    last_number3i = (last_number3 * pow(2,2))

    last_number4 = (binary_value[-4])
    last_number4i = (last_number4 * pow(2,3))
    
    decimal_value = last_numberi + last_number2i + last_number3i + last_number4i 
    
    print(decimal_value) 

    return decimal_value
```

The answer I'm trying to get is 11 when I key in 1011, but however, the answer I got instead is 111000011111111, can someone help me?

Comment: yeah I know it's kinda hard coded but I'm new so pls help My answer is 111000011111111

Comment: please read this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you expecting just a 4 number binary ? @pineapplez23

Comment: Are you actually calling your function somewhere?

Comment: @Astros yes, converting a 4 number binary to decimal

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking your input and transforming it to a list python thinks this is a list of strings (Your list will be `['1', '0', '1', '1']`), which explains why you are getting this answer `111000011111111`

For example python is taking '1' as a string and multiplying it by 3 which will give 111

In order to solve that issue you could either transform your list to a list of int or simply add `int(last_number)` to each one.

Comment: @pineapplez23 You're welcome, if you can mark the answer as the best answer so others could benefit and let people know that this problem was solved.